# Imaginary logo background messing with html

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

First things first I'd like to say that this is my first time doing it but here we go: I paid for a professional logo and asked for a transparent background.

When I received it, it was transparent as I asked for however when I went to resize it to use on my header, footer, menu, it feels like it is not transparent. It is like a square image with my logo in it, even though this "image" is transparent.

I know that it is difficult to picture this, so I printed my header so you could understand:

[image]

I want my logo to be aligned with my menu at the right corner however it won't to higher into the screen because this square around my logo is taking too much space, as if it was part of the logo.

This is weird because logo is transparent and there's nothing around it in my png image.
This is my div but I don't think it is a syntax issue.

```html
 <div class="pull-left logo-box">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
           <img src="images/TransparentLogo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo"/> 
        </a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Remove the unwanted transparent for logo using photoshop or online image editor.

Comment: There is a difference between "transparent" and "non-existent". If the transparent part of the logo is too big, then crop it. It's transparent, so it won't matter.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Thank you heaps!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really a coding issue, but an image file issue.